# Forward from struts1.2 to html resource

Tags: java, angularjs, struts, struts-1

I want to make forward from mine struts 1.2 application to the ususal html file. But always have `error 404 The requested resource (/gui-web/static/index.html) is not available`.

I have an `index.html` time in directory `static` which is available by direct access. But I cannot get it from struts.

Here is my struts-config.xml:

```
 <action
 path="/static/overview"
 type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
 parameter="/static/index.html"/>
```

I am migrating to Angular app on client side, that is why I need to specify those routes on the server.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found the way. I used the `<jsp-file>` property in `servlet` declaration and it works fine. Here is the snippet from `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>angular</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/static/index.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>angular</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/overview</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```